# Is it possible to access the TFS API using C++ (Native)

Tags: c++, api, tfs, tfs-sdk

Is there any way of accessing the TFS API using Native C++? I can access it using C# easily enough but I was wondering if anyone has tried accessing it via native C++.

My other option is to use C++/CLI - has anyone had any luck with that at all?

Cheers,
Dan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TFS API is defined in managed code and hence you will need some managed layer in order to access it.  There should be no problem accessing the API from C++/CLI.

Comment: I thought as much, thanks for the reply. It's for a pet/home project - after years in the VB wilderness I'm creeping back to C++ world and have recently discovered the joys of Qt :-)

Comment: This answer is not quite correct.  The sdk  for java comes with native dlls that is used by java code via JNI

Comment: Although it looks like you can't just use these native DLLs on their own. Most of the useful code is in the Java packages.

Comment: Any chance, I can have more information on this. I am trying to get Qt to work with TFS. Unable to find enough resources on this to proceed.